# how to make every month 30 day in php Datetime?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using modify and diff in Datetime class and some months have 31 or 29 or 28 days

i need to make php calculate every month as 30 day.

for Example:

```
$date = new Datetime("2017-05-05");
$date->modify("+ 30 day");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

the code above give me 2017-06-04

while i  need it to be 2017-06-05 ,because fifth month have 31 day

so i need a way to define new calendar that every months have 30 day

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve exactly. For instance, what do you expect the output to be when the original date is `xxxx/01/31`?

Comment: @DecentDabbler xxxx/02/1

Comment: But that's only 1 day difference, not 30. You should probably edit your question to include more examples of what exactly you expect in different edge cases.

Comment: @DecentDabbler OP means that if you end up with the 31st day of a month you round up to the first day of the next month (because he assumes each month is made of 30). It is like if you say 61 seconds. it is 1 second of the next minute

Answer (score 0):

You may use Carbon library for this.

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
use Carbon/Carbon;
$date = Carbon::createFromTimeString('17:00:00', 'Europe/London');
$plusThirty = $date->addDays(30);
```

Or, if you want to use PHP Datetime, you may trasnform it to timestamp, add 60*24*30 (30 days and transform it back).

```
Datetime::getTimestamp();
```